# Atom Editor header hidden below OSX menu bar

Tags: window, atom-editor

My atom header is unreachable and hidden below the OSX Menu bar. Any tipps to realign the editor?

[image: Window stuck]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can hit Window -> Zoom.
If that doesn´t work out, create a new "Desktop" in Mission Control and drag the Window on to that new Desktop.

Answer (score 1):

There is already an issue at github, which is closed. Have a look:

https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/3282

Comment: Thanks, this short answer helped me a lot: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25522065/atom-editor-header-hidden-below-osx-menu-bar/25522150#25522150